# How can I determine whether Kubernetes is using authentication for a image repository?

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to investigate why a pod has a status of `ImagePullBackOff`.

If `kubectl describe` the pod I see an event listed :

> Warning  Failed     5m42s (x4 over 7m2s)   kubelet            Failed
> to pull image
> "**********************":
> rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon:
> unauthorized: You don't have the needed permissions to perform this
> operation, and you may have invalid credentials. To authenticate your
> request, follow the steps in:
> https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication

This is not expected as I docker authentication set for the default service account - via a secret as mentioned here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/#add-image-pull-secret-to-service-account

How can I determine whether it's using the correct authentication so I can further debug this issue?

Comment: Created github issue here: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/94865

Comment: if you do `kubectl get <secretname> -o yaml` and then base64 decode the secret value, do the credentials look right?  ie- `echo "<secret value" | base64 -d`

Comment: Can you provide the answer [from this](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/94865#issuecomment-694503465)?

Answer (score 0):

**Not really an answer to the question but a solution in my case:**

Seems there is something wrong with the `kubectl patch serviceaccount default -p '{"imagepullsecrets": [{"name": "gcp-cr-read-access"}]}'` as it does not seem to do anything...

Instead I edited the service account resource directly - no `patch`...

Demonstarted here:

```
root@docker-ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-lon1-01:~/multitenant-manager# kubectl patch serviceaccount default -p '{"imagepullsecrets": [{"name": "gcp-cr-read-access"}]}'
serviceaccount/default patched (no change)
root@docker-ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-lon1-01:~/multitenant-manager# kubectl describe serviceaccount default
Name:                default
Namespace:           app-1
Labels:              <none>
Annotations:         <none>
Image pull secrets:  <none>
Mountable secrets:   default-token-tqp58
Tokens:              default-token-tqp58
Events:              <none>
root@docker-ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-lon1-01:~/multitenant-manager# kubectl get serviceaccount -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
items:
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: ServiceAccount
  metadata:
    creationTimestamp: "2020-09-17T15:50:34Z"
    name: default
    namespace: app-1
    resourceVersion: "111538"
    selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/app-1/serviceaccounts/default
    uid: 5fe21574-67bf-485c-b9aa-d09c1fe3350c
  secrets:
  - name: default-token-tqp58
kind: List
metadata:
  resourceVersion: ""
  selfLink: ""
root@docker-ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-lon1-01:~/multitenant-manager# kubectl patch -n app-1 serviceaccount default -p '{"imagepullsecrets": [{"name": "gcp-cr-read-access"}]}'
serviceaccount/default patched (no change)
```

Comment: The `patch` command reported (`(no change)`). As mentioned in the github issue the [supported API fields](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.19/#serviceaccount-v1-core) are case sensitive